# twisted: test my service's stop sequence

Tags: python, unit-testing, twisted, trial, twisted.internet

We have a complex multiservice that needs to do some fairly intricate accounting when shutting down in order to implement a "graceful" shutdown.

I'm trying to write tests for this under trial. The issue is that the reactor is effectively a  process-global resource, and shutting down my service means that trial's reactor is also stopped, which (of course) makes it explode.

This is [documented to be a no-no in trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/testing.html#auto3), but I need some kind of workaround that allows me to write my tests. My first thought was to use a [mock.Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/), but this means we're not really using a reactor that's shutting down, which isn't going to give me behavior that's faithful to the actual shutdown process.

I believe what I need is a way to separate trial's reactor from the reactor of my service-under-test. Sharing a mutable resource between the test system and the system under test is surely an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between shutting down a service and stopping a reactor.  You should be able to test most of the desired behavior with `myservice.stopService`.  To test the code that actually initiates the shutdown, just mock out `reactor.stop` with `self.patch(reactor, 'stop', mock.Mock())`, and later assert that it was called.  If you want to link the two, then have your mock `stop` call your service's `stopService`.